# Change the text of a button after a click using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am new to javascript and I am facing a problem with code:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form id="add-to-cart-form">
    <div class="cart">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="prince"/>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="First Form"/>
        <button id="btn_add" type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
</form>

<form id="add-to-cart-form">
    <div class="cart">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="lionel"/>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="Second Form"/>
        <button id="btn_add" type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
</form>

   
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#add-to-cart-form").submit(function(e) {

            $("#btn_add").html('Good');
            $("input[name='name']").val('Input change');

            e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
        });
    });
</script>
```

The purpose of my code is to change the submit button when the form is submitted and change of `value` of the input of the submitted form. But with my code, after submitting the first form, the submit button changes (this is normal) and the value of the input field of the second form changes (not normal). Also after submitting the second form, it does not work at all.

Sorry I tried my best to make the post clear. I am not a native english speaker.

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute. `id` must be unique within your document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The id should be unique per page**
Try it:

```
<form id="add-to-cart-form-first">
    <div class="cart">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="prince"/>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="First Form"/>
        <button id="btn_add_first" type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
</form>

<form id="add-to-cart-form-second">
    <div class="cart">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="lionel"/>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="Second Form"/>
        <button id="btn_add_second" type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
</form>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form").submit(function(e) {

            $(this).find("[type=submit]").html('Good');
            $(this).find("input[name='name']").val('Input change');

            e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is the duplicated IDs !

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH I noticed it in first line!

Comment: Thanks for providing for help but It does not work. It has solved only the value of the different input issue

Comment: @Prince what else do you want? https://jsfiddle.net/odL27tr2/ - for me it change the input value, button text and second button also work fine

Comment: Thanks. I did not change the line `$("#add-to-cart-form").submit(function(e)` in my code.

Comment: @Prince See, I told you someone would help you out. :)

Comment: @pmahomme, hahaha nice to see you around. Hope I will learn a lot from you.

Comment: @Prince mark as solved if is it )